# Combine OAuth and Basic auth in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, oauth, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have configured and working application with authentication provided by Spring Security. Here is configuration of authentication:

```
   <http pattern="/login" security="none"/> 
   <http pattern="/datastore/list" security="none"/> 

   <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
      <logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login" />
      <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?success=false"  default-target-url="/" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/repository/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/solr/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/WebISG/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/datastore/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
   </http>

   <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <authentication-provider ref="c2rAuthenticationProvider" />
   </authentication-manager>
```

Now i need to add to this service ability to use OAuth so that users will be able to use every one of these to methods and write the same URLs. Is it possible?